# Rails ransack filter on multiple instances

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

I have a poll app that allows to create polls as draft or published. Admin can see all. Users only published ones.
Then I am using ransack to filter.

This is my controller:

```
    @q = Poll.includes(:division).includes(:vote_options).ransack(params[:q])
    @p = Poll.where(published: '1').includes(:division).includes(:vote_options).ransack(params[:p])
    @polls = @q.result.order(:sort)
    @published_polls = @p.result.order(:sort)
    @display_polls = current_user.admin_role? ? @polls : @published_polls
```

As I needed to create two instances of Poll I added @p beside @q. And I'm not sure this is the right approach.

In my view I have

```
<% @display_polls.each_with_sortable_id do |poll, sortable_id| %>
```

For ransack filters I have:

```
<%= search_form_for @q, url: polls_path do |f| %>
```

Published and unpublished items show correctly as expected. But ransack filters won't work.

How can I make filters work again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it might be because your `search_form_for` is only searching on @q. I think this might be a better approach in your controller:

```
if current_user.admin_role?
    @q = Poll.includes(:division, :vote_options).ransack(params[:q])
else
    @q = Poll.where(published: '1').includes(:division, :vote_options).ransack(params[:q])
end

@polls = @q.result.order(:sort)
```

Comment: That was easy. Thanks a lot!